# Format/Prettyprint gql `template strings` in GraphQL Apollo-client (PhpStorm)

Tags: vue.js, phpstorm, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

When I have

```
query: gql`query FetchUsers { users {  id   email }}`
```

What is a fast way to make it look like this:

```
 query: gql`query FetchUsers {
                users {
                    id
                    email
                }
            }`
```

Or do I need to insert GraphQL expressions in another way in order to get readable formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install and configure `prettier` to your project. Then install [the Prettier plugin for Webstorm](https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html), which will add a `Reformat with Prettier` action and keyboard shortcut to Webstorm. You can also configure it to work with a file watcher to automatically reformat your file when you save it.

Barring that, if your GraphQL server is running either GraphiQL or GraphQL Playground, both of those tools have a "prettify" function to reformat the query. Or you could use some online tool like [this one](http://toolbox.sangria-graphql.org/format) from Sangria.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to install prettier, but  the Reformat with prettier action is always marked as disabled. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: You may have to tell it where Prettier is installed in Preferences.  `Preferences` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `Prettier`. You can also try `File` > `Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

Comment: That was it! Now I entered the path to the globally installed Prettier and it works. Thank you.

Comment: Any suggestions for VSCode?